# Extract substring using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

How to extract substring using perl regex for following?

```
Input: firstString123456lastString
Output: firstString

Input: first$String 123456 last@String
Output: first$String
```

Something similar to

```
echo "firstString123456lastString" | sed -e "s|\([a-z]*\)[0-9].*|\1|"
```

Comment: Please, define the rule applied to extract the substring

Comment: Return substring that comes before any number with in the input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'firstString123456lastString' | sed 's/^\([^0-9 ]*\).*/\1/'
firstString
$ echo 'first$String 123456 last@String' | sed 's/^\([^0-9 ]*\).*/\1/'
first$String
```

**Explanation:**

- `^`  Asserts that we are at the start.
- `[^0-9 ]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of numbers or space zero or more times.
- `([^0-9 ]*)` Matched characters are captured by the group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "firstString123456lastString" | perl -pe 's/^([a-zA-Z]*)\d.*/$1/'
firstString

$ echo 'first$String 123456 last@String' | perl -pe 's/^([^\d\s]*).*/$1/'
first$String
```